How filtering on multilevel hive partitioning works
If I partition my data by /YEAR/MONTH/DATE and my queries always looks like Day=[DATE], will my queries benefit from partitioning. I have seen many times people use /YEAR/MONTH/DATE partition but we rarely use all 3 filters in our queries(year=[YEAR] and month=[MONTH] and day=[DATE]).

No, skipping levels like that ignores partitioning.

depends on SQL actually and case by case - Assuming you have partition on  /YEAR/MONTH/DAY, 1. if you have a filter like where year(order_dt)=[YEAR] or where month(order_dt)=[MONTH], it will use partition. 2. But if you combine them in one clause, it wont use partition - like where to_char(order_dt,'yyyyMM')=[YEARMM] or wherre order_dt > [YYYYMMDD]
